# cant add click event to button in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

So I am following a tutorial and I have to add a click event to a button, like I've done many time before. For some reason it give me the following error: Ensure Event Failed.
I did see some questions on the internet that I have to declare a x:Class, but I have done that. It may be incorrect, but I don't know. Below is my XAML code.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:img_tutorial"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid ShowGridLines="true" x:Name="theGrid">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="211" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="387" Source="acces.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtImage"></TextBox>
        <Button Click="">Add Image</Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Could it be because click="" is hollow?

Comment: @EminNiftiyev No, in there I have to declare the button click event. Normally you'd just hit tab and it fills it in automatically. The problem I'm facing is that when I do that, it gives me that error message

Comment: `x:Class="MainWindow"` If not, this may be an error, please check. Add manually yourself

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! The mistake wasn't in my XAML code but in my Visual Basic. For some reason I cannot explain it set the Class as MainWindow3. I changed it to MainWindow and that allowed me to add my event.